# Failure to restore a table

Tags: backup, oracle-11g

I am getting familiar with the backup/restore process. For that reason, on Windows 7 I installed Oracle 11.2 g and started to play. Eventually I need to restore database on another server but first I want to try it locally.

First on the builtin ORCL db I created the table Test1, inserted one record and verified it from SQL Developer and sqlplus queries.

Then I took backup using following steps:

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup mount pfile='C:\app\Ilana\admin\ORCL\pfile\init.ora.52201722308
RMAN> CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT 'C:\backup\rman/full_%u_%s_%p';
RMAN> BACKUP AS BACKUPSET DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;
```

It created 2 files in `C:\backup\rman` e.g. `File1` and `File2`. I assume that `File1` is datafile and `File2` is control file.

Then I deleted table Test1

After that I restored ORCL using the following steps:

```
1. SQL> Select Dbid from v$database ;
1802923837
set Dbid=1802923837;
2. SQL> shutdown immediate;
startup nomount pfile='C:\app\admin\orcl\pfile\init.ora.512...' 
3. RMAN> connect target /
4. RESTORE CONTROLFILE FROM "\backup\rman/File2'
5. ALTER DATABASE MOUNT;
6. RESTORE DATABASE;
7. RECOVER DATABASE;
8. ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS;
```

After that I checked ORCL both in *SQL Developer* and *sqlplus* but I do no see my table Test1

**My question:**

What did I do wrong that Test1 was not restored?

Answer (score 0):

Someone from another forum pointed me to the issue.
My issue was that I restored everything i.e. I did complete Restore i.e. including 'table deletion' as well.
After I used parameter SCN I was able to restore 'incomplete' and get my table.